# Tips for using Notepad++ for rails development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notepad++

I just started using notepad++ for rails development.  Are there any plugins/options/tips that makes it easier to use for rails?

**Edit**
I ditched Notepad++ for Vim and it's been great.

Comment: Notepad++ is cool. Used it for years for php development. My only advice I can give you: Use the Obsidian color theme, its the best :-)

Comment: Yes, vim rocks, once you get over the initial steep learning curve.

Comment: It actually wasn't too steep.. I started using it in mswin mode which makes it work just about like notepad in insert mode.  Then I slowly started learning 'real vim' and used insert mode less and less.  Now I'm a total vim geek and even use the vim emulator in visual studio, haha.

Answer (score 11):

(For anyone looking at this in the future) I use [Light Explorer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/LightExplorer/) to get a TextMate-like directory browser in a sidebar; I use it all the time when I'm working in Rails.

Comment: it's EXACTLY the same as using native windows explorer and opening the files on notepad++ ...

Comment: @vsync: except the file explorer and editing areas are within the same window.

Comment: which makes the actual code area smaller..I prefer just leave the folder I'm working on minimized, as I work 90% of the time on the code on not staring at the directory structure.. :)

Comment: That's certainly a preference :D I hard wrap my code at 80 chars and I have a pretty wide monitor, so I like having the file structure in the remaining space.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) or [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) ... I know it takes a lot of memory, but it also validates a lot of your work, and gives good code completion.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ - "Plugins" - "Plugin manager" - "Show plugin manager" - "Explorer" OR "LightExplorer"

The plugin will show you the list of files & folders on the left.

The cool part - the plugin shows git/hg/svn overlay icons as well! So you can work with your source-controls right there - the context menus from TortoiseHG, TortoiseSVN will show up.

**Edit:**
Woops, the top answer already mentions "LightExplorer". Sorry. But - "Explorer" also worth a mention.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see you've already seen the light and switched to vim! ;-)

One great help to doing rails dev in vim is the rails.vim script, which adds enhanced syntax highlighting, quick switching between related files (i.e. jump from controller to model in one short command), and other handy features.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567